# Category of open sets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Sometimes we talk about the category of open subsets of a given space $X$. I was wondering if it's ever useful to define the following category:

- the objects are topological spaces
- the morphisms are inclusions of open subsets

In this category we would have that $U \cup V$ is the pushforward of the diagram with $U$,$V$, $U \cap V$.

Moreover I want to say that these are all the pushforwards. Indeed if I have $U$, $V$, and "inclusion of open set maps" $A \hookrightarrow U$, $A \hookrightarrow V$, then the pushforward should be $U \cup_A V$.

In general, I wonder if the following is true about arbitrary colimits.

- suppose $X$ is the colimit of some diagram. View the objects of the diagram as open subsets of $X$. There exists a sub-diagram containing some open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ as well as inclusions $U_i \cap U_j \hookrightarrow U_i$, $U_i \cap U_j \hookrightarrow U_j$ for each $i,j$.

Comment: Sounds like your objects are off.  If objects are spaces, morphisms should involve the spaces, not chosen open sets.  Or do you mean that $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$ consists of all injections $A \rightarrow B$ where $A$ is open in $X$ and $B$ is open in $Y$?  (But then what is composition?)

Comment: I kinda meant the following. Let $Hom(X,Y)$ consist of injective maps $X \rightarrow Y$ which map $X$ onto an open subset of $Y$, such that the topology of $X$ agrees with the subspace topology. Since an open subset of an open subset is open, this should agree with composition.

Comment: "pushforwards" = ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. a) What do you mean with "it's ever useful to define ..."? Of course this depends on the type of theorem / lemma you want to prove. The question is way too broad. b) In the 2nd question you talk about arbitrary colimits, but you speak of open subsets. ??

Comment: a) I thought it would be a natural extension of the category of open subsets of a given space. I was hoping that it would be a nice perspective to think of things like sheaves or a homology theory to be defined on this category.
b) Sorry, arbitrary colimits in the category defined at the start of the question (so morphisms are inclusions of open subsets).