# Colimit of monomorphisms is just coequalizer

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category, and let $\mathcal C'$ be the category with the same objects but morphisms the monomorphisms of $\mathcal C$.

Let's say a certain diagram has a colimit $A$ in $\mathcal C'$. Suppose there exist objects $\{A_i\}$ in this diagram such that the morphisms $A_i \rightarrow A$ do not factor through a family of morphisms $A_i \rightarrow B$ and a monomorphism $B \rightarrow A$.

In that case, is it true that $A$ is the colimit of the diagram containing each $A_i$, and for each $i,j$, the pullback $A_{ij}$ corresponding to morphisms $A_i \rightarrow A, A_j \rightarrow A$? If not, for what categories is it true? (For example, I think it's true for Set, and Abelian Groups.)

Also, when is it the case that every colimit has to have a sub-diagram with such $A_i$ and $A_{ij}$?

This is somewhat related to my other question at [Category of open sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4799417/category-of-open-sets). If I am spamming, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify the question. How many objects $\{A_i\}$ are required? Can we take the empty family? Then any condition is satisfied. Also, $A_i \to A$ factors as $A_i \to A \to A$. Do you want $B \to A$ to be a non-isomorphism? Have you looked at other example categories? I mean, of course the answer to your question is No, we cannot expect any compatibility between pullbacks and colimits. In fact, neither of these have to exist. Also, what kind of answer do you expect? Currently, this is a condition which some categories satisfy, but most don't.

Comment: Um I didn't think about empty family, so let's say it's not empty family. Yes I want $B \rightarrow A$ to not be an isomorphism. I guess the reason I asked is because I'm currently learning algebraic topology, and it seems like this "coequalizer for intersection of every pair of open sets" happens kinda often. For example, in the definition of sheaf, or Van kampen's theorem. I wanted to better understand why it's natural. (As vague as that sounds, I'm so sorry)

Comment: the motivation for your specific question is unclear. The whole thing to do with $B$ is also weird

Comment: The thing with $B$ is pretty natural, it just means something is maximal. The motivation is basically I want to better understand colimits in certain categories, since they express "gluing together".

Comment: As $A$ is the colimit in $C'$, the morphisms $A_i\to A$ lie in $C'$ and hence are monomorphisms. Therefore I do not quite understand the first assumption. Also note that for the colimit in $C'$ to exist, the diagram cannot have parallel pairs of morphisms, and any antiparallel pairs must be isomorphisms. So the diagram is essentially a preorder (I do not know if that observation really helps).